# Shading Using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectra

I am trying to shade the region under the emission line, but I am having trouble cutting off the shading at the continuum (represented by the straight red line). Anyone have a fix for this? I have been unable to find an answer.

These are the lines of code that handle the plotting and region shading.

`    # Plot the spectrum

```
plt.plot(wavelength1, fluxe1, color='blue', label='Spectrum')
plt.scatter(x_values, [yl, yr], color='red', label='Data Points')
plt.plot(x_values, y_values, color='red', label='Linear Equation')

# Shade the region for equivalent width calculation
plt.fill_between(wavelengths, fluxes, color='gray', alpha=0.5, label='Equivalent Width')

# Plot the intersection point
plt.axvline(x_intersect, color='red', linestyle='--', label='Intersection Point')

# Set the plot limits
plt.xlim(5650, 5750)
plt.ylim(0, 2.5)

# Add labels and legend
plt.xlabel('Wavelength (angstroms)')
plt.ylabel('Flux')
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5qcN.png)

Listed previously...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`plt.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) can take a second height argument, `y2`, so you can fill between two curves (by default it is set to 0).

```py
plt.fill_between(x=wavelengths, y1=fluxes, y2=y_values)
```

This will only work if `len(fluxes) == len(y_values)`, but you did not give enough information to run the code, so I cannot test it.

Comment: I was able to get it to work using your comments! Thank you for your help. I am sorry about the lack of information, this is my first post so still unsure of what to include or how much to include.

Comment: @AnalysisR When you post a question you should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which should be enough code to reproduce the problem while being as short as possible.

Comment: @AnalysisR If my solution answers your question then you can accept it by clicking the gray check next to my answer. This will turn the check into a green check.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, and the help with my problem.